# javascript extend child function from another parent

Tags: javascript, jquery

B extend A by `A.call(this)`, how to extend child function (A.method)?

```
function A()
{
    this.method = function()
    {
        // method A
    };
}

function B()
{
    A.call(this);
    this.method = function()
    {
        // method A
        // method B
    };
}
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to *derive* `A.method()` in the prototype `B`?

Comment: Yes, I want derive  A.method() in the prototype B.